strongly continuous one-parameter unitary group
Let $H = L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2) \subseteq H$. Show that $U_1(t) $ and $ U_2(t)$ are strongly continuous unitary groups.
Here , i have shown the isometry , Do i have to show Surjectivity now ? how can i show that ?
Let’s denote:
$$
U_1(t)f(x, y) = f(x + t, y)
$$
$$
U_2(t)f(x, y) = f(x, y + t)
$$
For any $ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$,
$$
\|U_1(t)f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x+t, y)|^2 \, dx \, dy.
$$
and ,  $$
\|U_2(t)f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x, y + t)|^2 \, dx \, dy.
$$
Changing variables $ u = x + t $, for $U_1(t)$ and $ v = y + t$ for $ U_2(t)$ respectively, the integral remains unchanged:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(u, y)|^2 \, du \, dy = \|f\|_{L^2}^2.
$$
and ,   $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x, v)|^2 \, dx \, dv = \|f\|_{L^2}^2.
$$
Thus, $ U_1(t) $ and $ U_2(t)$  preserves the $ L^2$-norm .

Yes, you still have to prove surjectivity. Moreover, you have to prove that $U_i(t + s) = U_i(t)U_i(s)$ and that $U_i(s) \to U_i(t)$ strongly as $s \to t$, for $i = 1, 2$.

i need to show isometry , surjectivity for unitary and $U_i(t+s) = U_i(t)U_i(s)$ , continuity for strong continuous ? i mean i am confused on :$U_i(t+s) = U_i(t)U_i(s)$ is for unitary or strong continuity ?@Falcon

$U_i(t + s) = U_i(t)U_i(s)$ to show that it's a group, surjectivity to show that it's unitary and $U_i(s) \to U_i(t)$ as $s \to t$ for the strong continuity.
